# Laravel 4 - Can't retrieve data in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a Quote model:

```
class Quote extends Eloquent {

    public function quote_lines() {
        return $this->hasMany('QuoteLine');
    }    

}
```

And a QuoteLine model:

```
class QuoteLine extends Eloquent {

    public function quote() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Quote');
    }

}
```

My table for this model is quote_lines.

Schema:

```
    Schema::create('quote_lines', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('quote_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('desciption');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->decimal('unit_price', 5, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::create('quotes', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('contact_id');
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The thing is I can't seem to access the quote lines from my Quote controller:

```
$quote_lines = Quote::find($id)->quote_lines;
dd($quote_lines);
```

Just returns NULL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method name for a relationship MUST be in proper camel-case in order to use the magic property. E.g., In order to use, `Quote::find($id)->quote_lines`, the method must be named `quoteLines()`

**Allow me to explain:**

Calling `Quote::find($id)->quote_lines;` activates the magic __get method in the Eloquent class.  __get() calls `getAttribute($key)` on the property being retrieved. So in this case, it calls `getAttribute('quote_lines')`

If the key (quote_lines) is not available in the model's attributes array, it will instead search for a method in the class. It does this by transforming the key via `camel_case()`. Laravel's camel_case() method will transform quote_lines into quoteLines. It then looks for a function in your class named quoteLines(), and treats it as a relationship method if its found.

Therefore, the relationship method MUST be written as quoteLines. (or any string that is proper camel case)

```
public function quoteLines() {
  return $this->hasMany('QuoteLine');
}
```

You may then access this relationship by using either `Quote::find($id)->quote_lines` or `Quote::find($id)->quoteLines` (both will work as both 'quote_lines' and 'quoteLines'  evaluate to 'quoteLines' when camel-cased.)

*Footnote: "camel case" in laravel refers to a string of this form: heyThereWorld. 
The first letter must be lowercase, and the first letter of all subsequent words must be capitalized*

Comment: so, I have shoppingMalls() expecting to become a dynamic property like $this->shopping_malls but no, it returns null. Anyone knows if  that changed in the future laravel versions?

Comment: @JosePalazuelos is shopping_malls an attribute or a relationship? An attribute would need the method name getShoppingMallsAttribute()

Comment: it is a relationship and I do not have an attribute named shopping_malls. I do not know why doesn't make the conversion to snake_case. I just changed the name to one word just to work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same problem with Laravel 4.1, and the solution suggested by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924514/laravel-4-cant-retrieve-data-in-a-one-to-many-relationship#comment26233687_17926165) solved it for me.

Putting an underscore *anywhere* in the function name causes it to return `null`:

```
public function quo_telines() {
    return $this->hasMany('QuoteLine');
}
```

Removing the underscore resolves the issue. Apparently, Eloquent doesn't like to have an underscore in the function name.

However, note that the function name must *not* match any of the schema's column names, or you'll get other issues.

Comment: To be specific: when writing a relationship method, the method name can't have underscores. The magic property being used must evaluate to the method name when passed through camel_case(), which removes spaces, underscores, and hyphens.

Comment: @TonyArra How do you know this? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Nope, I've just read most of the Eloquent source code. Check my answer above. Also, try not to post answers on really old threads like this. I didn't realize that you had revived it when I answered.

Comment: @TonyArra I'll always try to post answers to old questions. There's even a badge for it. This isn't a forum, you know.

Comment: It's mainly bad practice because it can make people like me waste time, thinking it's a new question, and in this case, they're talking about an older version of Laravel that might not work the way the current one does.

Comment: I don't know where you got that idea about making [people waste time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23996/192172). By the way, as far as I can discern, this question also pertains to the latest version of Laravel (4.1), as it was an issue I ran into with a fresh installation.

Answer (score 3):

You do not call the function, but you want to grab variable named `$quote_lines`.
Try to call `$quote_lines = Quote::find($id)->quote_lines();` instead.

Comment: Eloquent uses what's called magic properties I believe.  What he has is correct and does/should work.

Comment: Strange enough, when calling `$quote_lines = Quote::find($id)->quote_lines()->get();` it works. There's a problem here, `$quote_lines = Quote::find($id)->quote_lines;` should work as well.

Comment: I just tested exactly what you have, and came up with null.  The way to fix it is to change `public function quote_lines()` to `public function quoteLines()` and then use `$quote_lines = Quote::find($id)->quoteLines`.  Not sure why this makes a difference, but it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

like @Virtlink and @TonyArra said this error is fixed if you use camelCase name in relation functions (this solution worked for me). For example I had

```
public function origin_city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('City', 'origin_city_id');
}
```

This was not working, then I changed it to

```
public function origincity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('City', 'origin_city_id');
}
```

and it didn't work. Only when I used camel case conventions did it work

```
public function originCity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('City', 'origin_city_id');
}
```

Hope it helps others

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, it should be returning an empty eloquent object.

In your `QuoteLine` model, make sure you are telling Eloquent your table name.

`public $table = 'quote_lines';`

In setting up your relationship on your `Quote` model, be sure it knows what your foreign key is to link to your `quote_lines` table.

`return $this->hasMany('QuoteLine','quote_line_id');`

Comment: Well, the foreign key is on the quote_lines tables, isn't it how it's supposed to be set up?